# Can't convert DataGrid selected item to object type

Tags: wpf, datagrid, casting, selecteditem

I hope someone will be able to help me with this.  I've been at this from yesterday and getting nowhere.

I have a Data Grid holding a list of shares, Share being a type.
Each share contains a list holding the last 30 days share history.
I want to display the selected items history in a graph.

I don’t know if it’s possible to bind the graph direct to the datagrid but don’t think this will work for me as my next step is to allow multiple selections and plot them all on the one graph.

The most recentthing I tried as a test was:

String test = ((Share)ShareGrid.Items[ShareGrid.SelectedIndex]).Ticker;

Giving the error
{"Unable to cast object of type 'Share' to type 'ProjectMain.Share'."} 
ProjectMain being my namespace

I also tried

Share test = ShareGrid.SelectedItem as Share;

Test just stays as null.

I’ve tried a number of things around these themes but am obviously missing something so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Joe

More Detail:
I bind the portfolio list box as follows:

```
        PortfolioListBox.ItemsSource = MainWindow.LoggedOnUser.Portfolio;
        PortfolioListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I bind the share grid based on a portfolio list box as follows:

```
    private void PortfolioListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listPortfolio = (PortfolioListBox.SelectedItem as Portfolio);
        ShareGrid.ItemsSource = listPortfolio.Share;
        ShareGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

The XML for the portfolio list box is:

```
                        <ListBox Name ="PortfolioListBox" 
                                 DisplayMemberPath="name" 
                                 SelectionChanged="PortfolioListBox_SelectionChanged"
                                 DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

The xml set up for the Share grid is as follows:

```
<DataGrid   AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Name="ShareGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Extended" 
    SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionChanged="ShareGrid_SelectionChanged"
        CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="1" 
        FontSize="16" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}">
```

Comment: The message `Unable to cast object of type 'Share' to type 'ProjectMain.Share` suggests that you have two classes called `Share`, one in the `ProjectMain` namespace and one not in any namespace.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

That should work assuming an item is selected.

```
    Share test = ShareGrid.SelectedItem as Share;
```

You test is an items is selected with

```
    ShareGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0
```

If no item is selected the SelectedIndex will be -1

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Yea I thought that should work but it doesn’t.  Could it be something to do with the way I’ve set up the Data grid or the way I populated.

This is how it’s populated:

Portfolio listPortfolio = (PortfolioListBox.SelectedItem as Portfolio);
ShareGrid.ItemsSource =listPortfolio.Share;
ShareGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;

All suggestions are gratefully received.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Does your data show up in the grid? If Portfolio a public property?

Comment: Yes everything shows up in the grid as it should.  Portfolio is another class.

Comment: Understand Portfolio is a class.  Please post the code where you bind this DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added more detail above.

Comment: Both DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" look out of place to me. Try removing them one at a time.   And you can bind to ElementName and do it all in XAML.